# "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." how can I fix

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I searched about this problem, there were lots of issues about this but all answers were not useful , It did not solve my problem.  Firstly I can not make any changes on database, I have to keep column definition on database so how can I sort out this issue?

DATABASE DEFINITION:

```
[DeletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
```

C# CODE REPRESENTATION :

```
public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
```

I got an error:

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)....

I have tried this but nothing works for me

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
 public DateTime? PropertyName { get; set; }
```

EDIT : The problem was about I tried to send 0001/01/01  ... to datetime value to sql. and it had caused problem.

The FLUENT API solved my problem.

```
entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate").HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");
entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName("UpdatedDate").HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");
```

Comment: your column is not of type datetime2, but of type datetime. That means each time a DeletedDate has to be inserted/updated in your database, EF has to convert the passed DateTime2 to a DateTime value. Since DateTime has a lower value range than DateTime2, this may fail. Especially take care if you set it to the default, because a default DateTime object in c# is in the year 1, which is not in range of a datetime column.

Comment: so It is the reason asking for solution

Comment: the whole point is: you're passing a value you cannot save in the database in this column. Get rid of this value, either by setting it null, removing the row or whatever, or by actually migrating the database to the assumed model with column type datetime2.

Comment: But what if the colums are defined as datetime in database? What should I do?

Comment: if you still have that question, you should read my comments again.

Answer (score 0):

Your Property `DeletedDate` contains a value that is less than the supported value for `SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value`, before saving or updating database try

```
if(DeletedDate < SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
 DeletedDate = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value
```

Comment: I do not want to apply this solution. I want to represent as some format in C#(Fluent api or attribute tag) and get rid of problem.

Comment: and I do not want to assign Min value , I want to assign NULL

Comment: Can you update your question with your code which is throwing error?

Comment: Your method did not work.  I only have right to change C# side.  Question is  [DeletedDate] [datetime] NULL,  how I can pass value from C#? (I got an error) Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show your c# code which is throwing error?

Comment: thanks but the code is so long. impossible to share, I have to share all database and all save routine so It wont be effective and so difficult

Comment: `entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate").HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");
                entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName("UpdatedDate").HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");`

These lines are sorted out , problem WAS not about DeletedDate or NULL.